# Database column time is getting converted to local timezone

Tags: java, jdbc, quarkus

I've a Postgres SQL database with one column storing the time with timezone in UTC. In my Quarkus app I've defined the Entity as following:

```
public class Data {
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    public java.time.ZonedDateTime createAt;
}
```

Column as seen in PG SQL Client:

[image]

SQL definition I used to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
```

When I'm printing the createAt field, I see the time in my local time zone.

Can anyone please clarify where the conversion from UTC to my local time zone happening - while reading the database or while printing it?

Is there anyway I can enforce UTC timezone through out my Quarkus app?

Comment: you should check if the field has returns also UTC when you call `createAt.getZoneOffset()`. If this is not UTC (offset of 0 hours) the problem is in the output - you have to adjust it there. If it is not UTC, you should check the value in the database with another tool to see if it occurs on writing to the DB or reading from it.

Comment: @cyberbrain createAt.getZoneOffset() is returning -0.07 which is my local time zone. Offset should be 0 as the timestamp stored on DB is in UTC and ZonedDataTime should set it's timezone, is it correct understanding?

Comment: What is the datatype of the underlying database column? TIMESTAMP or TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE (a.k.a. TIMESTAMPTZ)?

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

[`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) is not mapped to SQL in JDBC. Use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), with offset of zero.

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class )
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

Caveat: I do not use Quarkus nor Jakarta Persistence (formerly JPA).

I’ll guess that the issue is due to  your use of `ZonedDateTime`. That type does not map to any standard SQL data type. (`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is a misnomer, SQL is actually ignorant of time zones.).

So I imagine somewhere along your tool chain, your JVM’s current default time zone is being applied implicitly while instantiating a `ZonedDateTime` object.

To fix this, retrieve date-time values from the database using only the types officially mapped in the JDBC specification, versions 4.2 and later.

For a column of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, retrieve as a `OffsetDateTime`. Since Postgres stores values in that column in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds), your resulting `OffsetDateTime` will carry an offset of zero too.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

*After* retrieval, assign your desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks Basil for the detailed answer. Initially, I tried java.sql.Timestamp which is the official JDBC mapping but decided not to used it as internally it uses the problematic java.util.Data. As you pointed out some where in the tool chain JVM is setting the timezone as -0.07 is set as the offset value when I tried OffSetDataTime type.

Comment: @Abhijeet You can easily verify the issue arising from your tool chain. Write a simple throwaway app that does nothing but connect to database and retrieve a row using `OffsetDateTime`. Add no libraries but the Postgres JDBC driver: no Quarkus, no entity manager, no ORM. I’m sure you’ll get an `OffsetDateTime` with an offset of zero.

Comment: @BasilBourque I guess the OP has a column of type TIMESTAMP instead of TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE (TIMESTAMPTZ), as the OP mentions `java.sql.Timestamp` being the official mapping, which is only the case for TIMESTAMP (WITHOUT TIME ZONE). In that case, as required by JDBC, the timestamp value is interpreted in the JVM default time zone.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The first sentence of the Question says “time with timezone”. I assumed that meant `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. But I now regret making that assumption. I should have insisted on clarifying the exact data type of column before posting this Answer. Thank you for your comments on both my Answer and the Question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I was trying bunch of types and java.sql.Timestamp is one of them. I've updated my question, I did use TIMESTAMPTZ while defining the column and PGSQL client also shows it's a timestamp with timezone. Hope this clarifies.